# Bundles in Translation Jobs

Tags: translation-manager, bundles

If we `retry sending` a Translation Job on an error, it's *agnostic* of item updates (somewhat similar to items in the Publishing Queue).

How does a Translation Jobs handle a Bundle and the items the Bundle references, in terms of the following?

- Translation Job:

  - **Creation** (Job stores just a reference to the Bundle?)
  - **Start**
  - **Errors on individual items** -- I'm guessing the individual items from Bundles would show in the Translation Job Error tab.
- What happens for Bundles set to dissolve?
- Are **nested Bundles** flattened to include all items?

And are folders and Structure Groups handled the same way?

**Edit**: added a question on nested bundles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundles, folders, structure groups, categories, keywords, search pages, and pages all work the same way:

When the user add an item to a job, it stores a reference to that item only. The tab is called "Added items" in an attempt to make it clear that this is not the actual translation item, just the one you added to the job. I am not sure how successful the naming is at making this clear though... it's easy to see the name is not perfect, not so easy to come up with another name that is.

When the translation job is send for translation the actual translatable items are resolved. This can include the bundle itself but typically doesn't.

Once the resolving has been done Translation Manager pretty much ignores the item you originally added - it only deals with the items that were actually send for translation. This also means errors are reported on the items actually send, not the items you added to the job.

If you open the job after the bundle was dissolved (or a folder deleted after the translatable items where moved out of it etc) it simply won't show in the Added Items list anymore (you could easily argue it should, but you will have a very hard time arguing this is the most important feature to add to TM :) ).

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a better suited name than `Added Items` except for maybe something with the term "reference." But reference feels a bit technical and out-of-place since we don't use it elsewhere. Maybe a visual (icon) distinction with a familiar metaphor could make it easier (like Windows shortcuts or similar)?

Comment: And thanks for another great explanation. I see parallels with Publishing where the Translation Job *include* options are like publishing's link resolving and sending the job is like queuing a publish transaction. The publish transaction and its "packaged" contents are not the actual items in the same way that an in-progress translation job doesn't have the actual items.